# CoreOS / rkt / systemd - how to access low-numbered ports?

Tags: iptables, systemd, coreos, containers, rkt

[originally asked at Stack Overflow but put on hold there with the suggestion that I ask here.]

I have a web app, written in go, which accepts traffic on ports 80 and 443. It works fine if I:

- copy the executable binary to a server running CoreOS
- `sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+eip' executable-name`
- invoke the program manually, as an unprivileged user

I am now trying to run it under rkt, in a container built with acbuild:

```
acbuild begin
acbuild set-name myapp
acbuild copy myapp /app/myapp
acbuild set-exec -- /app/myapp
acbuild set-working-directory /app
acbuild mount add etcssl /etc/ssl
acbuild mount add cacert /usr/share/ca-certificates
acbuild set-user 500
acbuild set-group 500
acbuild write --overwrite myapp.aci
acbuild end

...

sudo rkt run  ...  --net=host
```

This works fine if I have the app listen on high-numbered ports, but I have been unable to get it to work listening on ports 80 and 443.

I have tried:

1. `echo '{ "set": ["CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"] }' | acbuild isolator add "os/linux/capabilities-retain-set" -`

   `sudo rkt run  ...  --net=host`

   This does not appear to have any effect, since ListenAndServeTLS returns:

   `listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied`
2. Change the app to listen on 8480 and 8443.

   `acbuild port add http tcp 8480`

   `acbuild port add https tcp 8443`

   `sudo rkt run  ...  --port=http:80 --port=https:443`

   The app runs and does not report any errors but never sees any in-coming requests.
3. Change the app to listen on 8480 and 8443.

   `sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80  -j REDIRECT --to-port 8480`

   `sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443`

   `sudo rkt run  ...  --net=host`

   The app runs and does not report any errors but never sees any in-coming requests.

   Note: I am not experienced with `iptables`, and I may very well be doing something incorrectly. `iptables -nvL` gives the same output before and after I run the above two commands, so I'm not sure they are actually doing anything.
4. I tried running `rkt` under `systemd` with `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`, but that also fails with `bind: permission denied`
5. I also tried adding `--caps-retain=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` to the `rkt run` command line, but that didn't help.
6. If I remove the `set-user` and `set-group` acbuild lines, the app does work, but it runs as root, which negates one of the main purposes of running in a container - reducing privilege for the sake of security.

I'd appreciate any insight anyone can offer. Thanks.

**EDIT: There has been [a brief discussion of this in the rkt-dev group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rkt-dev/1-c9t4dDZUw/EFetW0FuBgAJ) and there is [a github issue tracking it](https://github.com/rkt/rkt/issues/3672). For my current purposes, I have found that systemd alone, without rkt or any other container runtime, provides sufficient protection, and I've switched to it, so I won't be following this issue any longer.**

Comment: Try reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/linux-allowing-an-user-to-listen-to-a-port-below-1024). Ports below 1024 are privileged.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd already seen that page and tried everything listed there, as detailed above. (I did not mention authbind, but my CoreOS installation doesn't have it, nor am I aware of an easy way to install it in CoreOS.) My problem is that I'm not able to make any of those solutions work with a program running inside a container under rkt.